# What should we do with answers on duplicate questions?

Tags: discussion

In [Confusion in the usage of みえます and みられます; きけます and きこえます [duplicate]](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/19584/confusion-in-the-usage-of-%E3%81%BF%E3%81%88%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99-and-%E3%81%BF%E3%82%89%E3%82%8C%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99-%E3%81%8D%E3%81%91%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99-and-%E3%81%8D%E3%81%93%E3%81%88%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99), there are some pretty good answers which will probably now never be seen since it was marked as a duplicate of [What is the difference between 見える／聞こえる and 見られる／聞ける?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/5287/what-is-the-difference-between-%E8%A6%8B%E3%81%88%E3%82%8B-%E8%81%9E%E3%81%93%E3%81%88%E3%82%8B-and-%E8%A6%8B%E3%82%89%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B-%E8%81%9E%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B)

For one, I feel bad for the answerers, but also it's simply hiding good content from visitors. Is there some way we can merge the new answers into the old question or some other solution which doesn't have these downsides?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a question is 100% identical (EDIT: The 'merge command guideline' says 99%), moderators can actually merge questions rather than close them as duplicates. If you find a candidate for merging, feel free to flag for moderator attention.

This case does look like a good merge-candidate... so I've done the merge and edited the title to include the furigana.

---

Do note that the duplicate questions are linked in both directions on the right-hand sidebar.

Comment: By the way, when a question **with no answers** is closed as a duplicate, logged out users can't see it―they get automatically redirected to the question it's a duplicate of.  But if there are answers, then it doesn't redirect.